# Set Vue JS select option from two values

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a Nuxt JS / Vue JS application with an address finder that I'm building using getaddress.io

I have a `<select>` element with a load of counties, fetched from the data object. When a user types in a postcode, it should set the county `<select>` with a matching county from the API.

However, not all counties are listed or match within my code, so I need to check if what's fetched from the API matches a particular field, and if not, utilise the **district** key.

Here's my JS method that runs when selecting an address after addresses have been found:

```
/**
 * Pick address
 */
addressPickerSelection: function addressPickerSelection(addressKey) {
  const cleanedPostcode = this.formData.AppPostCode.toUpperCase()

  var addressRaw = this.address.addressList[addressKey]
  var cleanAddress = {
    house: (addressRaw['building_number'] != '') ? addressRaw['building_number'] : (addressRaw['building_number'] === '' && addressRaw['line_1']) ? addressRaw['line_1'] : '',
    street: (addressRaw['thoroughfare'] != '') ? addressRaw['thoroughfare'] : (addressRaw['thoroughfare'] === '' && addressRaw['line_1']) ? addressRaw['line_1'] : '',
    town: (addressRaw['town_or_city'] != '') ? addressRaw['town_or_city'] : '',
    county: addressRaw['county']
  }


  this.formData.AppPreviousPostCode = (cleanedPostcode != '') ? cleanedPostcode.replace(/ /g,'') : ''
  this.formData.EmpPostCode = (cleanedPostcode != '') ? cleanedPostcode.replace(/ /g,'') : ''

  this.formData.AppHouseNumber = cleanAddress['house']
  this.formData.AppStreet = cleanAddress['street']
  this.formData.AppTown = cleanAddress['town']
  this.formData.AppCounty = cleanAddress['county']

  this.formData.EmpAddress = cleanAddress['house']
  this.formData.EmpAddress2 = cleanAddress['street']
  this.formData.EmpTown = cleanAddress['town']
  this.formData.EmpCounty = cleanAddress['county']

  if (addressRaw['district'] != '') {
    var countySelectValue = this.formData.AppCounty
    this.formData.AppCounty = addressRaw['district']
    if (this.formData.AppCounty == '') {
      this.formData.AppCounty = countySelectValue
    }
    countySelectValue = ''
  }

  this.address.addressSelected = true
}
```

`cleanAddress['county']` may not always match an item from my array of counties, whereas `addressRaw['district']` might, so in the case of `cleanAddress['county']` not being found, or matching, it should utilise the district.

For example:

1. I type a UK postcode in
2. I select an address, and "Mid Glamorgan" doesn't exist in my array of counties, it should utilise the district.

This is the part of the code that I'd like to work, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
if (addressRaw['district'] != '') {
    var countySelectValue = this.formData.AppCounty
    this.formData.AppCounty = addressRaw['district']
    if (this.formData.AppCounty == '') {
      this.formData.AppCounty = countySelectValue
    }
    countySelectValue = ''
  }
```

This is a common issue, where someone needs to set a select item to be one of two possible values if one doesn't exist.

Where am I going wrong?